# ggplot2 manual legend not displaying

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've searched the interwebs hard for why I cannot add a legend to my ggplot2.

```
g.2plot1<-ggplot(input_csv,aes(x=R_OD_MONTH,y=DAMWAMT))+
geom_line(colour = "black")+
geom_line(aes(x=R_OD_MONTH,y = SCALED_PERCENT_MW), colour = "blue") +
scale_colour_manual(name="Legend", values = c("black", "blue")) +
scale_linetype_manual(name="Legend", values = c("dashed", "dotted")) 

g.2plot1
```

When I do this, I get nothing, no errors in the console and no legend on the plot. Would someone please tell me what I'm dong wrong?

```
dput(head(input_csv))

structure(list(OD_MONTH = c("12/1/2010", "1/1/2011", "2/1/2011", 
"3/1/2011", "4/1/2011", "5/1/2011"), DAMWAMT = c(219869.89, 214323.24, 
193976.03, 249174.62, 213529.32, 226318.98), NB_MADE_WHOLE = c(39L, 
37L, 26L, 45L, 74L, 64L), NB_CONSID_MW = c(818L, 871L, 874L, 
831L, 1060L, 1418L), PERCENT_MW = c(0.0404, 0.048, 0.0371, 0.0616, 
0.0604, 0.0525), SCALED_PERCENT_MW = c(151898.635570388, 183223.057973301, 
138297.241632282, 239277.287536408, 234331.326104369, 201770.413343447
), R_OD_MONTH = structure(c(14944, 14975, 15006, 15034, 15065, 
15095), class = "Date")), .Names = c("OD_MONTH", "DAMWAMT", "NB_MADE_WHOLE", 
"NB_CONSID_MW", "PERCENT_MW", "SCALED_PERCENT_MW", "R_OD_MONTH"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Legends are drawn for aesthetics. Since `colour` is not an aesthetic in your case, there is no legend. It is a bit complicated to answer your question without data. Could you post some of your data, e.g. by posting the output of `dput(head(input_csv))`?

Comment: can you give the first 10 lines of input_csv? We cant answer without seeing your data generally ...

Comment: original post edited with data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legends are drawn for aesthetics. Since `colour` is not an aesthetic in your case, there is no legend. The trick is to convert your data from wide format (where every type of data has its own column) to long format (where there is a column indicating the data type and a column giving the corresponding value). This is done as follows:

```
library(reshape2)
plot.data <- melt(input_csv,
    id="R_OD_MONTH",measure=c("DAMWAMT","SCALED_PERCENT_MW"))
```

`melt` returns a data frame in long format with the column indicating the data type called `variable` and the column with the values called `value`.

Now you can let ggplot pick the colours by mapping the column `variable` on colour:

```
ggplot(plot.data,aes(x=R_OD_MONTH,y=value,colour=variable)) + geom_line() +
   labs(title="My plot",x="x-axis",y="y-axis",colour="colours") +
   scale_colour_discrete(labels=c("this","that"))
```

The last two lines show, how you can add a plot title, change the axis labels and the legend title (`labs()`), and change the labels in the legend (`scale_colour_discrete`).

Comment: Well I guess I'll get with the program and do it the right way. Thanks. Now i'm searching around for a way to change the labels in the legend without changing the colors as the default choices are way better than my manual ones :).

Comment: I added code to change the labels. ggplot2 may seem a bit complicated at first (it did for me...), but is in my opinion the best choice for plotting in R. It is definitely worth putting some effort into learning it properly. The [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/) is an excellent ressource for information and examples on ggplot2.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I tried that but obviously not. It works now.